# How to fix "The Project needs to include ATL support" in Visual Studio 2019 C++?

Tags: visual-studio, com, visual-studio-2019, atl, atlcom

I add an ATL project in my main solution, but further on adding a new atl simple object in that project I get the error "The project needs to include ATL support". However if I just open the atl project individually in a new Visual Studio Window, I can create it.
For the fix I also used

```
class CGFXComOBJECTNAMEModule : public CAtlDllModuleT< CGFXComOBJECTNAMEModule >
{
 public:
  DECLARE_LIBID(LIBID_GFXCOMOBJECTNAMELib)
  DECLARE_REGISTRY_APPID_RESOURCEID(IDR_GFXCOMOBJECTNAME, "{ID here-}")
};

CGFXComOBJECTNAMEModule _Module;
```

as I saw this fix on internet
[FIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594856/how-can-i-add-an-atl-simple-object-to-old-atl-dll-project-upgraded-to-vs-2010)

still getting the same error! CAn anyone please help me regarding this?